# Media container does not get synchronized when I sync the staged version of a catalog with the online one

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If I try to synchronize a product from the `staged catalog` with the one on the `online catalog` it won't synchronize the `media container` field.

This is the product in the online catalog
[image]

And this is the product for the staged version of the catalog:
[image]

I tried to debug the `CatalogVersionSyncJobModel`  in order to see if there is any bug related to this field in the sync process, but with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Login to backoffice and select **System** > **Multithreaded Synchronization** from the left panel
2. Select the **sync powertoolsProductCatalog:Staged->Online** from the right panel
3. Open **ADMINISTRATION** tab and scroll down to find **Sync attribute configurations**
4. Double click **Media Container** from the list of attributes. [Note: If you are not able to find the attribute due to limited space in the list box, you can double-click any attribute in the list and then you can select the desired attribute from the popup window]
5. Change the value of **Synchronize** to **True** and click **SAVE**.

You can also do it using the following ImpEx script:

```
UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig;syncJob(code)[unique=true,path-delimiter=!];attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code),qualifier)[unique=true];includedInSync;copyByValue
;"sync powertoolsProductCatalog:Staged->Online";Product:mediaContainer;true;true
```